# How to add Singleton in startup class using Factory method's return value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying using DI add in my startup class Singleton. I would like to based on **processorStringName** which comes from appSettings and Factory class add proper processor?
Is it possible to do this in a nice way?

```
 IProcessor processor = ProcessorFactory.CreateProcessor(Configuration, processorStringName);
 services.AddSingleton<IProcessor, processor>();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
services.AddSingleton<IProcessor, processor>();
```

This won't work because `processor` is a variable name, not a type-name.

[Please review the overloads for `AddSingleton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

You want this instead:

```
services.AddSingleton<IProcessor>( implementationInstance: processor );
```

Or this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IProcessor>( implementationFactory: sp => processor );
```

Comment: You can also use `services.AddSingleton<IProcessor>(processor);`

Comment: @juunas Good catch, I've added that now.